# Send edited data to bottom of datatable

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datatable, mariadb

How to send recently edited data to bottom of datatable? I currently use `orderBy('updated_by', 'asc')` as orderBy in Laravel but I want to another data that I haven't edited yet to order as `created_at`, `desc`.

Any advice how can I achieve this?

```
$model = Assigned::select(
    'maintenance_assigned.id', 'maintenance_assigned.member_id', 'maintenance_assigned.created_at',
    'member.username', 'member.full_name', 'member.phone', 'member.call_status',
    'user.nik AS assigned_to_nik', 'user.name AS assigned_to_name',
    'panel.name AS panel_name'
    )
    ->leftJoin('maintenance_members AS member', 'member.id', 'maintenance_assigned.member_id')
    ->leftJoin('users AS user', 'user.id', 'member.assigned_to')
    ->leftJoin('maintenance_panels AS panel', 'panel.id', 'member.panel_id')
    ->orderBy('maintenance_assigned.updated_at', 'asc')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To conditionally order by a different column, you would need to use an expression.  This can be done using `orderByRaw()` or `orderBy()` with an `Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression` object.  The expression might be `IF(updated_at = created_at, NULL, updated_at)` or similar.

Another option would be to populate another field on update, such as `updated = 1` and sort by that column instead.  Keep in mind that more complicated sorting can affect index usage and performance.  If the table will be large, you should EXPLAIN the query or profile it with a realistic dataset.